# Recording a call with webRTC

Tags: webrtc

I'm implementing a video chatting service and I need it to be monitored and archived.

All the conversations are done 1 on 1 and have to be written to a file with audio and video (can be to separate files from each user, but has to be kept on the server), I can't figure how that could be done.

I'm using peer.js to connect the two clients together so to my understanding there is no server in between the two users that could keep the data.

Comment: Either route the call through the server so that it can record it or record it on the client and then upload it to the server.

Comment: Any tips on how that could be done?